# Query multiple Tables using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, count

I am currently working on a system. This is how my tables look like:-

**sales table:-**

```
ID     |     avatar     |   ident
-------------------------------------
1     |    img/photo11 |   CCS7771
2     |    img/photo32 |   INL0987
3     |    img/photo32 |   INL0987
4     |    img/photo6  |   URS8827
5     |    img/photo32 |   INL0987
6     |    img/photo9  |   NSU8837
7     |    img/photo3  |   PPP9998
```

**kudos table:-**

```
ID     |     sale_id   |   ident_id
-------------------------------------
1      |       1        |   INL0987
2      |       4        |   INL0987
3      |       7        |   INL0987
4      |       1        |   KKU8837
5      |       1        |   URS8827
6      |       4        |   SHD8837
```

So I have this like system, and when A user press the like button to the table row, it stores the `sales.id` and `sales.ident` into another tables named `kudos`, like you can see above.

I am trying to query to see how many people have given kudos for each post. You can see in the above tables, example: the sales.id 1 has gotten 3 kudos from INL0987, KKU8837 and URS8827. I have tried a few different ways, but I cant seems to find a solution for this. This is what I have tried:

```
     /* $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT kudos.sale_id as makesName, sales.ident AS modelsName from kudos,sales where kudos.sale_id = '42' AND kudos.ident_id = sales.ident"); */
     $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT kudos.sale_id as TheID, sales.ident AS TheIdent from kudos,sales where kudos.sale_id = '42' AND sales.id = kudos.sale_id");
     
     echo $resultSet->num_rows;
     
     while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
         $iid = $rows['TheID'];
         $iident = $rows['TheIdent'];
         
         echo "<br><br>TheID: $iid";
         echo "<br>TheIdent: $iident";
     }
```

Can someone help me out here? I can figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: When you tried that way, what was the result? Were you getting an error, null, no output, the wrong output (wrong values), duplicates ... ? I'm thinking you need a GROUP BY in there so that it sums the values for each id.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Forgot to mention that. The output I get in `echo $resultSet->num_rows;` is correct. It gives the the number of kudos given to that sale. Also the `TheID` is correct, but the `TheIdent` is not correct. `TheIdent` returns the ident for the user who added the sale, not the user who gave kudos to that sale.

Comment: Ah, then maybe all you need is to change `sales.ident` to `kudos.ident_id`... which then begs the question why join those two tables in a query anyhow? Guess I'm still a little confused on your intended output.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Yes, I actually made it work now, I guess I just added that by a mistake. That one has bothering me for a few hours now haha! Now I just need to get the number of kudos given for each sale, and get that into the code I already have.

Comment: Finding number of kudos per sale could be handled by the answer from GMB below. The first sql would group (count) all kudos by sale.

Comment: @IncredibleHat May I ask: I already have a query that get all the sales like this: `SELECT * FROM sales`. How can I add the new query to display the number of kudos gives for each sale?

Comment: @IncredibleHat I think we posted at the exact same time ^ . So the answer he postet, should I replace that inside the: `$resultSet = $mysqli->query("` ?

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to query to see how many people have given kudos for each post

I think you just want aggregation:

```
select sale_id, count(*) no_kudos
from kudos
group by sale_id
```

If you also want to include `sale_id`s that have no match in `kudos`, then you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select id, (select count(*) from kudos k where k.sale_id = s.id) no_kudos
from sales s
```

Comment: Hehe `no_kudos` ... no kudos? That could be better understood as `num_kudos` I think. Maybe its a regional thing.

Comment: How can I `echo` out the values from this? In my website: the sales looks like a look-a-like facebook/instagram feed, so each sale has its own kudos button, and I want to add the number of kudos gives next to that button on each post.

Comment: I want to echo the `avatar`, but also the number of kudos given on that sale. Not sure how I can do this in the same code, because if I do example: `echo $rows['avatar'];` inside the `while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {` I get error: `Notice: Undefined index: avatar in`.